# Change value with Koin injected variable

Tags: kotlin, koin

I need to assign a new value to my single Koin variable, but Koin does not allow to use var on the injected variable...

```
private val userAssets: UserAssets by inject()
```

How set value on userAssets?
Or have another thing to do to make UserAssets Singleton?

```
val dataModule = module {
    factory {
        RetrofitBuilder(
            androidContext()
        )
    }
    single { LoginCredential() }
    single { UserAssets() }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally do not use Koin, so I can not verify it, but Koin also provides a way to directly retrieve an instance with `get()`. So in your case:

```
private var userAssets: UserAssets = get()
```

Might work so you can later reassign it, at least that is what I understand from their their [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/quick-references/koin-components/).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try with Declaring injection parameters, here the [reference](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-core/index.html#_declaring_injection_parameters).

In the module you can write:

```
single { value : String -> UserAssets(value) }
```

then you should be able to use inject

```
val userAssets : UserAssets by inject { parametersOf("value") }
```